# Unable to restart Hadoop daemons after quit from hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have installed Hadoop and Hive with MySQL metastore. I started Hadoop daemons then I started Hive shell. The problem that I am facing is that, when I quit hive shell, using "quit" command, my Hadoop daemons are also get stopped. After then, when I restart my Hadoop daemons, using start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh, then the NameNode, DataNode and ResourceManager are not starting. What is the problem with my configurations? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I got it! 
The thing is, first I started the **Hadoop Daemons**, then I checked to ensure, using JPS, and I got:
[image]

and after then, I issued a query using hive, to check out the available tables:

[image]

After the hive query, I again checked for the Hadoop Daemons using jps, but I got nothing on the terminal:

[image]

So, whenever I issue the Hive related stuff, daemons goes off from the terminal. I am not able to see them using jps.

Despite the daemons are not showing on the terminal, they are running at the background in fact. I confirmed this when I issued a command to create a repository in the HDFS and it got created:

[image]

I checked the user interface of the NameNode and Cluster also, It was showing all the information.

Okay! But my concern is, how to stop those background running Hadoop daemons without restarting my machine?